# ios - How to use a chained blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, imgur

I'm a newbie with code blocks. I came across this method declaration in Imgur API.

```
+ (void)uploadImageWithFileURL:(NSURL *)fileURL success:(void (^)(IMGImage *image))success progress:(NSProgress * __autoreleasing *)progress  failure:(void (^)(NSError * error))failure;
```

Whats the right way of using this sort of methods? It gives me a compiler error when I try to use it as a chained blocks.

This is how I tried

```
[IMGImageRequest uploadImageWithFileURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"/temp.jpg"] success:^(IMGImage *image) {

    } progress:(NSProgress *__autoreleasing *){

    }failure:^(NSError *error) {

    }];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show *how* you are trying to use it. There is nothing special about blocks, you only have to be careful for the massive amounts of `( ) { }`

Comment: added it to the questions itself for easier viewing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^` means pass a block of code with parameters as described, the double `*` on the NSProgress object means you allocate an object (pointer), then pass a pointer to that pointer...

```
NSURL *fileURL = // create a URL
NSProgress *progress;

[SomeClass uploadImageWithFileURL:fileURL success:^(IMGImage *image) {
    // success code goes here
} progress:&progress  failure:^(NSError * error) {
    // error code goes here
}];
```

SomeClass is the class that provides this (class) method.

Comment: Daaamn, was he just a few seconds quicker :/ @danh you missed including the `fileURL` in the actual call

Comment: Thanks to you too for trying to help :)